# Electron - Update label in menu

Tags: menu, electron

I try to update label on menu item when I click this menu item. It should works like click->'show' label, click->'hide' label. This is my code:

```
const template = [{
  label: 'Menu',
  submenu: [{
        label: 'Search',
        click() {
            win.webContents.executeJavaScript("showSearch()"); // it run function changeSearch() in main.js
        }
    },
    {
        label: 'Resetuj',
        click() {
            win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html?del=1`);
        }
    },
    {
        label: 'Quit',
        accelerator: 'Q+CmdOrCtrl+Q',
        click() {
            win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html?logout=1&close=1`);
        }
    }]
}];
```

**changeSearch()** I tried something like this:

```
Menu.items[0].submenu.items[0].label = "Changed label";
```

Comment: Hey I was wondering if the answer I posted solved your problem. If you would like more information or if things are still unclear then feel free to ask. If you feel like my answer was able to help you successfully then please consider marking it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
function addMenuItems(items, position) {
const updateSearchItems = [{
    label: 'newOptionDisabled',
    enabled: false,
}, {
    label: 'newOptionWithAction',
    enabled: true,
    key: 'newOptionWIthAction',
}, {
    label: 'Do some stuff',
    visible: false,
    key: 'doSomeStuff',
    click: () => {
        // stuff
    },
}];


 items.splice.apply(items, [position, 0].concat(updateSearchItems));
}
```

By defining your menu items as an object that you can reference you can always modify the object later. In my example I use a addMenuItems function that enables me to specify where I want to insert these items within the existing object.

Answer (score 0):

I did this to change/modify my menu item dynamically:

```
const menuTemplate = [{
    label: 'Options',
    submenu: [
       {
         label: 'Hide',
         click() { 
            changeLabel('Show'); // Put logic here
         }
       }
    ]
}];

function changeLabel(label) {
    menuTemplate[0].submenu[0].label = label;

    // Rebuild menu
    const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(menuTemplate);
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
}
```

**This code is not tested!**